# Image swiping from top to bottom or bottom to top

Tags: android, swipe

I have bunch of images.I want to show all images one by one through swipe top or bottom. Also if last image displayed and I swipe again top to bottom then first image will appear.

Comment: Have you tried something or asking for written code ?

Comment: @MukeshKumar i tried for left to right swipe and that is working fine, but i want top to bottom.

Comment: you should post your code here for better response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this git may help you..

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer

try this...